# How to use the onHide option of angular-strap's modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-strap

I use angular-strap and the modal service. I try to invoke a function when closing the modal with the parameter onHide.

```
var _modal = $modal({
            templateUrl: "app/pages/fee/modals/historic/fee.historic.html",
            controller: "HistoricController",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            keyboard: true,
            show: false,
            onHide: function() {
                console.log("Close !");
            },
            onShow: function() {
                console.log("Open !");
            }
        });
_modal.$promise.then(_modal.show);
```

But when I close my modal nothing happens, I don't see any of my log (close or open) in the console.
Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas !

Comment: There does not seem to be any issues with the code that you have included. Can you provide more code that shows your controller configurations. Duplicating this in  JSFiddle would be helpful also.

Answer (score 5):

After some investigation it turns out to be a funny case.

It appears that `$modal` is out of sync in the distributed versions! I mean when angular-strap is fetched by bower or npm.

1. Take a look at your own local version of angular-strap, not even in  latest version 2.3.8 you can find references to `onShow` or `onHide`
2. Take a look at the source on the github repo -> https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-strap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js

Here `onShow` and `onHide` is actually fired! So it seems that modal is out of sync with the rest of angular-strap in the distributed versions.

It is not the documentation that is wrong (which I actually believed in a long time) but the source we download that is not uptodate!

So if you want support for `onShow`, etc, you must merge the latest `/modal` from the github repo into your local angular-strap. Personally I will not do that since it will cause all kind of problems when upgrading and so on - I stick with my original answer, but now at least I know why I have to do so.

---

To my experience usage of the `onShow` etc options is useless. I use handlers on the `modal.show` / `modal.hide` events, which always is broadcasted. If you have a multi modal environment (modals over modals), "tag" the modals to avoid confusion.

```js
var _modal = $modal({
  templateUrl: "app/pages/fee/modals/historic/fee.historic.html",
  controller: "HistoricController",
  controllerAs: "vm",
  keyboard: true,
  show: false,
  tag: 'myModal'
}

$scope.$on('modal.show', function(e, target) {
  if (target.$options.tag == 'myModal') {
    //do stuff here
  }
})
$scope.$on('modal.hide', function(e, target) {
  if (target.$options.tag == 'myModal') {
    //do stuff here
  }
})
```